Can anone identify this IC marked `55JT`?
Please help me identify the IC pictured below:



Please zoom out a bit to see how it connects to nearby components. It will help solving what it is.

It's a Texas Instruments LM95245 temperature sensor.


(Source: aliexpress.com)
